# Launching Chrome in remote debugging mode

Tags: google-chrome, remote-debugging

To launch Chrome in remote debugging mode, I right-click on the Chrome shortcut on my desktop and add the --remote-debugging-port=9222 command to the Target field. This causes Chrome to launch in remote debugging mode every time I double-click the shortcut icon on the desktop. I want my Excel Workbook_Open VBA to launch Chrome through this shortcut so Chrome opens in remote debugging mode when the workbook is opened?

I specify the shortcut path correctly as in the code below, but it gives an error 53 -file not found.

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim x As Variant
Dim myPath As String

myPath = "C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk"
x = Shell(myPath, vbMaximizedFocus)

End Sub
```